# Saving decimal value from oracle to mongodb

Tags: c#, oracle, mongodb

I built some application to convert data from oracle to mongodb.
the application works fine, until some error occurred.
the error is `Specified cast is not valid`.

I tried to check the data to oracle, and I found some records have field that value is `1.4211E-14`.

I use `OracleDataReader` for receiving the value. I've tried to convert it to decimal using this code:

```
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

...

decimal value = 0; 
if (decimal.TryParse(reader.GetString(i), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
    document.Set(reader.GetName(i), Convert.ToDouble(value));
else {
    var v = reader.GetDecimal(i) / (decimal)1000000;
    document.Set(reader.GetName(i), (float) v);
}
```

or even this:

```
document.Set(reader.GetName(i), Convert.ToString(reader.GetDecimal(i)));
```

the exception still occurred. what should I do to save the `1.4211E-14` as numeric data in mongodb?

I cannot save the value directly to mongodb because mongo didn't recognize decimal value.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you keep your decimal values as a string? Just save them as a decimal and use `GetDecimal` method to get them?

Comment: The update doesn't have anything to do with using the wrong type. Just *don't* convert to string. Read the value with `GetDecimal()` and pass it as is, or explicitly convert it to a BsonDouble.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried `new BsonDouble(reader.GetDecimal(i))` it showing error. what should I do to save it as bsondouble ?

Comment: *What* error? Who throws the error? Mongo or Oracle? How do you store the decimals in Oracle? In a numeric field or a varchar field? Also don't try to read and write in the same line, it makes debugging impossible. Put the `Get` statements in separate lines and check their values before trying to call `Set`

Comment: Also, BsonDouble doesn't have a constructor that accepts `decimal`.

Comment: the error that I mean is "BsonDouble doesn't have a constructor that accepts decimal"

Comment: the data comes from different server, and actually is not my data. I'm just the one who access the data and convert it to mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got stuck I didn't get any solution yet. So I made changes directly on the query. cast the field as string, and then convert it to double in C#

```
SELECT ..., TO_CHAR(a_field) as a_field FROM table;
```

and then

```
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

...

var field = reader.GetName(i);
if (field.equals(a_field) {
    document.Set(field, Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetString(i)));
}

....
```

and this one works.